# Vue 3 v-model binding on a nested input component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to migrate my components in Vue 3. I find it confusing on how to set the V-model especially on a nested component. Initially, the checkbox should not be checked since I'm retrieving a value from the API. Where should I initially set the v-model for this nested component?

```
CheckboxFieldComponent.vue

<template>
    <div v-show="isVisible">
      <FormCheckbox
        v-model="booleanFromStoreConvertedToArray"
        :input-value="field.model.itemId"
        :title="title"
        :id="field.valueField.id"
        :class="field.model.cssClass"
        :name="field.valueField.name"
        :checked="true"
        :required="required"
        :disabled="!isEnabled"
        @input="
          onInput(value);
          $emit('change');
        "
        @focus="field.tracker.onFocusField(field, value)"
        @blur="field.tracker.onBlurField(field, value, errors.value)"
      />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  extends: BaseField,
  computed: {
    booleanFromStoreConvertedToArray: {
      get() {
        const isSelected = this.value;
        if (isSelected) {
          return [this.field.model.itemId];
        }
        return [];
      },
      set(value) {
        this.value = value.length > 0;
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
FormCheckbox.vue
<template>
  <FormCheckboxBase
    :checked="shouldBeChecked"
    type="checkbox"
    :class="$style.check"
    :input-value="inputValue"
    :title="title"
    :id="id"
    :name="name"
    :required="required"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    @updateInput="updateInput"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    FormCheckboxBase,
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    inputValue: {
      // this is the value that will be assigned to the html element's value-property
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    shouldBeChecked() {
      if (!this.value) {
        return false;
      }
      return this.value.includes(this.inputValue);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      const { checked, value } = event.target;
      const newValue = [...this.value];
      let checkLabel;

      if (checked) {
        checkLabel = 'on';
        newValue.push(value);
      } else {
        checkLabel = 'off';
        newValue.splice(newValue.indexOf(value), 1);
      }

      // this.$emit('input', newValue); <--- This is from Vue 2 which was working
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
FormCheckboxBase.vue

<template>
  <div :class="$style['form-item']">
    <input
      :id="id"
      :value="inputValue"
      @change="updateInput"
      :type="type"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      class="input"
      :class="$style.input"
    />
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'checkbox',
    },
    inputValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    checkboxList: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      // this.$emit('updateInput', event); <--- This is From Vue2 Event Emitter
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I just use this Basefield as the extended component so I can trigger the `onInput` event and when I trigger the check / input field, it triggers twice and doesn't change the value

```
BaseField.vue

onInput(value) {
   this.value = value;
   // validate
   this.validate();
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to do v-model on a component?

According to the [official document](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html), `v-model` on component will expands to:

```html
<CustomInput
  :model-value="searchText"
  @update:model-value="newValue => searchText = newValue"
/>
```

Therefore, if you set `v-model` on `FormCheckbox`, you have to set `modelValue` as a prop to get the binding value, and `$emit` `update:modelValue` to achieve two-way binding.

Change this in *FormCheckbox.vue*:

```js
props: {
  value: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [],
  },
  ...
}
```

to:

```js
props: {
  modelValue: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [],
  },
  ...
}
```

---

#### Nested binding issue of checkbox

In *FormCheckboxBase.vue*, if type of `<input>` is checkbox, `v-bind:value` won't apply to `checked`. You have to set `v-bind:check` in *FormCheckboxBase.vue*:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      :id="id"
      :type="type"
      :checked="checked"
      :required="required"
      :value="inputValue"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      @change="updateInput"
    />
  <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

---

#### Why is the event triggered twice?

If you set `@input` on `FormCheckbox`, it will be triggered when the checkbox `checked` changed. However, `this.value` in *CheckboxFieldComponent.vue* haven't be changed until `@change` is triggered. (`onInput` will be triggered earlier than `onChanged`.)

Moreover, `this.value` will be set by the setter of `booleanFromStoreConvertedToArray`. That means you have also done the two-way binding of `this.value` in this `v-model`.

So you just have to do the validation under the setter of `booleanFromStoreConvertedToArray`:

```js
booleanFromStoreConvertedToArray: {
  get() {
    const isSelected = this.value;
    if (isSelected) {
      return [this.field.model.itemId];
    }
    return [];
  },
  set(value) {
    this.value = value.length > 0;
    // do anything you want after setting this.value
    this.validate();
  }
}
```

---

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/question-77194739-f9wm4g

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue with the v-model!